# Linux + replace STRING/WORD in file according to rule

Tags: linux, shell-script, sed, perl, ksh

My target is to replace any word/string/Any characters in file 
with new word/string according to the following rules:

1. If numeric characters on the left side of word/string then we not replace the word
2. If numeric characters on the right side of word/string then we not replace the word

remark - numeric means any number or [a-z] or [A-Z]

The following Example described file before , and file after:

I want to replace the word "$$OLD_WORD$$" with "&&NEW_WORD&&"

example 1 -  file Before replacement

```
  more file 

  ABC$$OLD_WORD$$ABC
  $$OLD_WORD$$GG
  $$OLD_WORD$$
  1$$OLD_WORD$$
```

example 2 - file after replacement

```
  more file

  ABC$$OLD_WORD$$ABC
  $$OLD_WORD$$
  &&NEW_WORD&&
  1$$OLD_WORD$$
```

So in order to replace the word regarding the rules (1,2) that I mentioned 
I write the following syntax (this Perl command exists in my ksh script)

```
     perl -pe 'next if /^#/; s/(\Q|[[:^alnum:]])$ENV{OLD_TEXT}(\E|[[:^alnum:]])/$1$ENV{NEW_TEXT}$2/g' file
```

But this perl command not does the replacement as example 2 !!!

The following Example described what I get from my Solaris/linux machine:

```
    export OLD_TEXT='$$OLD_WORD$$'
    export NEW_TEXT='&&NEW_WORD&&'

     perl -pe 'next if /^#/; s/(\Q|[[:^alnum:]])$ENV{OLD_TEXT}(\E|[[:^alnum:]])/$1$ENV{NEW_TEXT}$2/g' file




      &&NEW_WORD&&&&NEW_WORD&&&&NEW_WORD&&&&NEW_WORD&&&&NEW_WORD&&                  &&NEW_WORD&&ABC$&&NEW_WORD&&$&&NEW_WORD&&OLD_&&NEW_WORD&&WORD$&&NC
          &&NEW_WORD&&&&NEW_WORD&&&&NEW_WORD&&&&NEW_WORD&&&&NEW_WORD&&&&NEW_WORD&&    &&NEW_WORD&&$&&NEW_WORD&&$&&NEW_WORD&&OLD_&&NEW_WORD&&
      &&NEW_WORD&&&&NEW_WORD&&&&NEW_WORD&&&&NEW_WORD&&&&NEW_WORD&&&&NEW_WORD&&     &&NEW_WORD&&1$&&NEW_WORD&&$&&NEW_WORD&&OLD_&&NEW_WORD&
```

**Please advice what I need to fix in my perl syntax in order to get  results as  example 2?**

.

Comment: `OLD_TEXT="$$OLD_WORD$$";` won't work as you expect in shell cause `$$` will be replaced with pid. use usual quotes `'` instead of double `"` : `OLD_TEXT='$$OLD_WORD$$';`.

Comment: No should be work see the syntax in my perl command "\Q" "\E" they should ignore from this characters

Comment: It happens before perl. Just try this two commands: `export OLD_TEXT="$$OLD_WORD$$" ; echo $OLD_TEXT` and `export OLD_TEXT='$$OLD_WORD$$' ; echo $OLD_TEXT` and try to find some differences.

Comment: see my update in my queastion

Comment: Could you explain/fix your example 2? It is for me not logical why the 2nd $$OLD_WORD$$ is not replaced.

Comment: You right Jofel - I fixed my quastion thx for this important remark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use negative look-behind/-ahead:

```
export OLD_TEXT='$$OLD_WORD$$'
export NEW_TEXT='&&NEW_WORD&&'

perl -pe 's/(?<![[:alnum:]])\Q$ENV{OLD_TEXT}\E(?![[:alnum:]])/$ENV{NEW_TEXT}/g' file
```

gives

```
ABC$$OLD_WORD$$ABC
&&NEW_WORD&&
&&NEW_WORD&&
1$$OLD_WORD$$
```